# a、bのどちらでもない場合、という条件を指定したい

Tags: python

```
if index != 2.356 or index != 2.36:
```

現在上記のように、if文の後、条件を書いているのですが、うまく動作しません。
”indexが2.356,2.36のどちらでもない場合”
としたいです。どのように書けば上の文章のように記すことができるでしょうか.
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`or`ではなく`and`を使います。

`or` の場合 「～でないか　～でない」となって左論理式が真の場合真、左論理式が偽の場合右論理式が真になり論理式全体が常に真になります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに動作させると、すべて真で通っていました。修正してうまく出来ましたので、しっかりと把握しておこうと思います。

Comment: この `index` および `2.356` という値が浮動小数点数として扱われるのであれば、単純な等値比較は危険なような気がします。いやオイラ [tag:python] は良く知りませんけど・・・

Comment: そうですね。ありがち。回答する時に一応試してみましたが思ったように動作するようです。

Answer (score 6):

基本はBLUEPIXYさんの回答のように`and`を使うのがよいと思います。
その他の方法として、

#### 連鎖

```
2.356 != index != 2.36
```

大小の比較などではよく使うと思いますが、不等式でもこのように出来ます。

> 比較はいくらでも連鎖することができます。例えば x < y <= z は x < y and y <= z と等価になります。
>   http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

#### 帰属

```
index not in (2.356, 2.36)
```

この場合、`index`の値が、`(2.356, 2.36)`というタプルに含まれているか調べています。
比較対象が多かったり動的な場合によいと思います。

> 演算子 in および not in は、帰属 (membership) を調べます。 x in s の評価は、 x が s
>   の要素であれば真となり、そうでなければ偽となります。 x not in s は x in s の否定 (negation) を返します。
>   http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/expressions.html#in

Comment: ありがとうございます。pythonすごく便利でびっくりしました！簡単にコードを書こうと思えば、こちらもとてもいいですね。

Answer (score 2):

浮動小数点数の単純等値比較は危険なので注意喚起しておきます。

```
index=2.0;
index+=3.0/10;
index+=5.0/100;
index+=6.0/1000;
print index;
print index==2.356;
```

と言うコードを python 2.7.5 に食わせると、結果は

```
2.356
False
```

となります。

コンピュータの中で使われている浮動小数点数の動作は、
プログラマが勝手に期待している動作とは異なる挙動を示すことがあります。

上記比較の結果が `True` になってほしいのであればまた別の工夫が必要です。
もし興味があれば別質問を投げていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 比較が危険というよりも、浮動小数点の計算では誤差が出る（貯まる）事がある、という説明の方が分かり易いかと思います。`print index` の時点で`index`は 2.3559999999999994 になってしまっています（printでは丸めて出力されますが）。 つまり、‘index‘が本当に 2.356（例えば`index = 2.356`として代入している）なら問題ない。けれど、`index`を計算で求めているのであればヤバかも、という事でよいでしょうか。

Comment: まあそういうことなんですが、この辺の詳しい話はこの質問の議題からはオフトピだと思ったので「危険」とだけ書いてお茶を濁しています。そもそもソースコードに書いたリテラル `2.356` も、コンピュータのメモリの中での内部表現では厳密一致していませんし・・・

Comment: `t=0.001; if abs(index - 2.356) >= t and abs(index - 2.36) >= t: ...`という感じですかね。tはtolerance,つまり許容範囲。